# Can't set a folder to wallpaper

Tags: wallpaper, big-sur

I'm now using Big Sur Beta 11 I can't set a folder to make wallpaper through system preference. Are there any way to set wallpaper folder without using system preference?

I've tried this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    -- RANDOM ROTATION OF A FOLDER OF IMAGES
    tell current desktop
        set picture rotation to 1 -- (0=off, 1=interval, 2=login, 3=sleep)
        set random order to true
        set pictures folder to file "/Users/mankuang/Desktop/ManKuang/wallpaper"
        set change interval to 5.0 -- seconds
    end tell
end tell
```

but there is an error message:
`結果： error "「System Events」發生錯誤：無法將「file \"/Users/mankuang/Desktop/ManKuang/wallpaper\" of current desktop」設定成「file \"/Users/mankuang/Desktop/ManKuang/wallpaper\" of current desktop」。" number -10006 from file "/Users/mankuang/Desktop/ManKuang/wallpaper" of current desktop`

Comment: What happens if you try to set a folder in System Preferences?

Comment: it show a blank page:[link]https://ibb.co/cXWn8fS

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?